# Can't access datalist control ID in code behind

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, controls, datalist

I'm trying to bind a list of strings to a datalist. I'm trying to do the binding in a controller and the datalist is in a view(chtml file). I keep getting the error : "The name "datalist id" does not exist in the current context".

Any idea how I can fix this issue?

```
<input list="cardProgram" class="form-control input-group-lg">
<datalist id="cardProgram" runat="server" />
```

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindCardPrograms(sender, e);
}

private async void BindCardPrograms(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:59066/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new 
            MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        ViewBag.country = "";
        HttpResponseMessage response = await 
            client.GetAsync("api/Profile/InitializeCardProgramSelection");
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            List<String> cardPrograms = 
                response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<String>>().Result;
            var builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            foreach (String filename in cardPrograms)
            {
                builder.Append(String.Format("<option value='{0}'>", 
                filename));
                cardProgram.InnerHtml = builder.ToString();
            }
        }
        /*else
        {
            return View();
         }*/

    }
}
```

Comment: This appears to be `asp.net webforms` rather than `asp.net mvc`, could you clarify?

Comment: This is asp.net mvc. I'm not sure what to clarify

Comment: `runat=server` tends not to be used in MVC due to the use of Razor syntax instead, hence my confusion as to whether it was webforms or MVC.

Comment: Specifically, you seem to be trying to use a WebForms control in a Razor view. That is simlpy not going to work. MVC has a different approach to creating the page contents.

Comment: @ Christoph Herold, what makes the above a webForms control?